# What are the limitations in the Dungeon Defenders Demo?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I just played the first level and the first challenge in the dungeon defenders Demo. After some tries I wanted to purchase a pet but ended up only having 5000 Mana. I wonder if this is a cap in the demo?

Are there other limitations besides having only one map to play?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm upgrading now, since it's a lot of fun.  The limits (as seen by me) are:

1. Max 5000 mana.
2. Max Level 10 characters.
3. You can only play the Apprentice and the Squire.
4. You only get 2 dungeons (the one you start in, and a challenge map).
5. Only 10 pages in your item box (this could be for the retail game too, not sure).
6. You cannot do the Ladder online play, only the normal one.

That's all I noticed as limitations.

Comment: Could it be, that Hard and INSANE modes remain locked for the 2 available levels?

Comment: There was a max of 10 pages of items in the retail-game; now it's been bumped up to 15.  They might have increased it for the demo, too.

Answer (score 2):

My boyfriend purchased the game, and I did not, but I was allowed to play with him and had full access to all the game mechanics whenever he was in my party.

Recently, I tried playing without him. I only had access to demo mode, and I LOST ALL MY MANA. I had saved up a little over 100k playing alongside my boyfriend, but it was reverted back to 5k as soon as I had started the demo version on my own. The next time I tried to load the game even with him in my party, I only had 5k.

Comment: So you're saying that you were able to gain over the demo cap? Were you able to go over the max when not playing with him?

Answer (score -1):

I left the demo with 8.5k mana but when I came back I had 5000, so there is a cap of 5000 mana.